# JQuery Not working in IE7 but working in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Here is my javacript function which is calling JQuery function.

Below code is working fine in IE10 but not working in IE7 (stops at JQuery function)

```
function test()
{
//before calling JQuery function display message...
alert("Before");
//JQuery function...
$("#boxscroll").getNiceScroll().resize();
//After calling JQuery function display message...
alert("After");
}
```

**Result in IE10**

> Before
>
> After

**Result in IE7**

> Before
>
> (stops at **JQuery $("#boxscroll").getNiceScroll().resize();**)

**you can refer JQuery here...**
https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script> 

<script> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
var nicesx = $("#boxscroll").niceScroll({nativeparentscrolling:false,touchbehavior:false,cursorcolor:"#CCC",cursoropacitymax:0.5,cursorwidth:6,autohidemode:false,horizrailenabled:false}); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: What's getNiceScroll() ?

Comment: When it stops, what is the error message?  What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: what version of jquery are you using? also what is the getNiceScroll()? Is it some external library? Is it compatible with IE7? Also, what is the error message?

Comment: Either your plugin is not compatible with ie7, or you're using jquery 2.0, which dropped support for ie7.

Comment: @robertc : there is no error message.. nothing happens in IE7.. actually it should get executed and run the next alert statement

Comment: Nicescroll is a jquery plugin,
Compatible with all desktop browser: Firefox 4+, Chrome 5+, Safari 4+ (win/mac), Opera 10+, IE 6+. (all A-grade browsers)

Comment: @wumm : I have modified my question to tell about getNiceScroll. Please see

Comment: @Sbml : Ya, Nicescroll is working.. but when i call this function $("#boxscroll").getNiceScroll().resize(); in IE7 , nothing is happening... and script stops there itself.. but works in IE10

Comment: @Sbml : jquery2 ? what should i do now then ?

Comment: Does it works without `.resize()` ?

Comment: jQuery 2 does not support IE 7... and what should you do?  Downgrade to a jQuery version that supports it.

Comment: Amazing, @Sbml 's answer is working :) anyone have idea on the problem then ?

Comment: I am not sure, why people had down voted this question which is having a tricky answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#boxscroll").scroll(function(){
  $("#boxscroll").getNiceScroll().resize();
});
```

Comment: inside the javascript function ?

Comment: thanks.its working.. could you please let me know whats the problem ?